# Python iterate through multiple lists and start from index 0 each time

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to iterate through multiple lists, but begin with index 0 for each list. For example, the code gives output

```
lists = [[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[1,6,5]]

p=0
    
for i in lists:
    for li in i:
        p += li
        print(p)
```

```
1
3
6
8
11
15
16
22
27
```

but I want the output to be

```
1
3
6
2
5
9
1
7
12
```

I'm new to Python, is there other ways to implement this?

Comment: Put the `p=0` line below the `for i in lists:` line (with proper indentation). This way, the value of `p` is set back to `0` when you get the next list to iterate over.

Comment: Be aware that there are no indices in this code. ``i`` is a list and ``li`` is a value in that list. Your desired result amounts to resetting the running total ``p`` to ``0``, not changing anything about indexing.

Answer (score 2):

Set the value of p to 0 before the inner loop.

```
lists = [[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[1,6,5]]
    
for i in lists:
    p = 0
    for li in i:
        p += li
        print(p)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set p = 0 on every item of lists

```
lists = [[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[1,6,5]]

p=0
    for i in lists:
    p = 0
    for li in i:
        p += li
        print(p)
```

The output is

```
1
3
6
2
5
9
1
7
12

Process finished with exit code 0
```